# Extreme values without using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Extreme values of $f(x, y)=y^{2}+\frac{x^{2} y}{2}+2 y+x^{2}$ on $\partial D$, $D=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 8,2 y+x^{2} \geq 0\right\}$

$f$ can be rewrited as: $$f(x,y)=\left(1+\frac{y}{2}\right) \left(x^2+2y\right)$$

$x^2 + 2y \geq 0$, so $\left(1+\frac{y}{2}\right) \leq 0 \implies y \leq -2$ for the min. Given that $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 8$, $(\pm 2,2)$ is a min.

How to proceed to find the max?

Comment: Rewriting it as $(2y+x^2) (1+\frac{y}{2})$ may help.

Comment: I know that $\left(2y + x^2 \right) \geq 0$, so $\left(1+\frac{y}{2}\right)$ should be negative for the minimum?

Comment: Yes but as $x^2+y^2 \leq 8$, if we take value of $y \lt -2$, $2y+x^2$ becomes negative. So I think the function minimum is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I need to find a condition for the max value. Maybe with $x^2=8-y^2$ or there is an easier way?